# ga:producBrand and ga:productVariant behaviour inconsistencies

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to query the Google Analytics Reporting API with the following dimensions:

ga:productSku,
ga:productName,
ga:productBrand,
ga:productVariant,
ga:date,
ga:transactionId

and metrics:

ga:itemQuantity,
ga:uniquePurchases,
ga:itemRevenue

About 60 rows are returned when querying at this level, but when I remove both ga:productBrand and
ga:productVariant, about 1640 rows are returned.

My question is, why does adding the two columns cut so much data out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google analytics is a multidimensional database, not a relational database.   The only way you will get data back is if all the data exists for all of the dimensions and metrics you are requesting.

There is appartly a lot less data avaiable for

ga:productSku, ga:productName, ga:productBrand, ga:productVariant, ga:date, ga:transactionId

and metrics:

ga:itemQuantity, ga:uniquePurchases, ga:itemRevenue

than there is for

ga:productSku, ga:productName, ga:date, ga:transactionId

and metrics:

ga:itemQuantity, ga:uniquePurchases, ga:itemRevenue

Which would imply that some of your data does not have ga:productBrand, ga:productVariant,  associated with it.